# How to display variables inside nested ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs

how to execute below type code in angular js

```
 <tr  ng-repeat="x in gLists" > 
   <td  ng-repeat="z in gfLists" >{{ 'x.'+{{z.field}}} </td>         
 </tr>`
```

Comment: Try this. remove outer braces x.{{z.field}}

Comment: Question syntax - reg. For multiline code, place cursor to a new line, press `ctrl+k` or the `{}` button.  From mobile, 3 newlines and 4 spaces before start. Then you will get a proper formatted code

Comment: but i need to execute outer code as angular script just see like first execute z.field and given result x.name then also want to execute for {{ x.name }} dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
<tr  ng-repeat="x in gLists" > 
   <td ng-repeat="z in gfLists">{{ 'x.'+ z.field }} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for the property accessor:

```
<!--
<tr  ng-repeat="x in gLists" > 
   <td  ng-repeat="z in gfLists" >{{ 'x.'+{{z.field}}} </td>         
</tr>
-->

<tr  ng-repeat="x in gLists" > 
   <td  ng-repeat="z in gfLists" >{{ x[z.field] }} </td>         
</tr>
```

Bracket notation first evaluates the contents of the brackets and uses that as the identifier of the desired property.